# Eclipse Bundle Pool not syncing plugins?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Before I ask this question, I want to say that i might not have fully grasped the concept of bundle pools in Eclipse.

The way i understand it is this: Say you have multiple installations of Eclipse (one for Java, one for C/C++, one for HTML and javascript) and you have several plugins you want to use for each install. Rather than installing the same plethora of plugins across all your installs, you can just install these plugins to a bundle pool and link the pool to your eclipse installs.

If this is not the idea behind bundle pools, please correct me.

Assuming i have understood the idea of bundle pools, how would one go about "installing" a plugin into the bundle pool?

Comment: I think the Eclipse Oomph installer that most Eclipse downloads use already does this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. When having multiple installations, a bundle pool saves disk space by avoiding duplicated bundles.

A **plug-in is installed into an installation** with its own configuration area, **not into the bundle pool**. The bundle pool is just a common location for one or more installations instead of the `features` and the `plugins` subfolders per installation. Regardless of whether a bundle pool is used or not, the installation of a plug-in checks whether the required bundles already exist or have to be downloaded from an update site.

When using the [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) to install or to upgrade a complete product or some plug-ins the `-bundlepool` argument is being used to specify the bundle pool directory:

- For separate installations: the installation directory
- For installations using a common bundle pool: the common bundle pool directory

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. So the bundle pool offers a place to put the plugins, and for each installation i just have to point to the pool to grab the plugins and configure them per install?

Comment: @PaulVandenBroeck Yeah, sort of. A bundle pool is something like the local Maven repository is for your Java application: instead of storing the JARs per project (e. g. in a subfolder `lib`), the JARs are stored in a common location and the same JAR can be used by multiple Java application. The `config.ini` refers to a p2 profile which contains the installation history of an installation. I extended my answer with a link to the p2 director, which can be used on the command line to create an installation or to install plug-ins into an existing installation.